# Throw ConstraintViolationException with orElseThrow method at Save time of Employee

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, crud

I am learning Spring Boot and I want to show error message at save time if any employee field is empty at save time. But `orElseThrow` method shows me error. How can I do that at save time?

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Add an employee")
    @PostMapping("/createemployee")
    Employee createOrSaveEmployee(
            @ApiParam(value = "Employee object store in database table", required = true) 
            @Valid
            @RequestBody Employee newEmployee)
            throws BadRequestExceptionHandler, ConstraintViolationException {

/*in below line orElseThrow method shows error
  that create new method named as orElseThrow in Employee Pojo. */

        return employeeRepository.save(newEmployee)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ConstraintViolationException("Required parameters can not be empty."));
    }
```

Comment: The repository `save` method doesn't return an `Optional`, you can't use `orElseThrow`. I don't know what kind of DB you're using, but if some fields are required at DB level, then the ORM framework should raise an exception if you try to insert rows that doesn't match the expectations. Just do some investigations to know what kind of exception is thrown in this case and handle it

Comment: "...error that create new method..." Would you rephrase it as "...orElseThrow method shows error: Create new method named as orElseThrow in Employee Pojo"?

Answer (score 0):

`Optional` returns can be handled with `orElseThrow()`. Instead of trying this way, you can pretty much cover the same exception in this way and also your own way of throwing the exception.

```
try{ 
  employeeRepository.save(newEmployee); 
}catch(ConstraintViolationException e){ 
  throw new OwnDefinedException("Required parameters can not be empty."); 
}
```

Comment: constraint Violation Exception does not accept string, it accepts set value. i tried what you have written here.

Comment: I have updated, You can throw your own defined exception if it is constraint violation. You can also add multiple exception to handle in the same fashion.